If it had I would call
It started raining an hour ago. When John and Samantha walk over to the window, they see that it hasn't stopped raining yet. The have the following dialog:
Samantha: "The rain hasn't stopped yet!"
John: "If it had, I'd call Peter, and we could all go hiking in the forest."
Are the bolded tenses used correctly in this context? Thanks.

my reply to Samantha's observation would be no sh*t Sherlock

Third conditional - expressing regret..
OP's sentence is a mix of Third conditional + Second Conditional.

Ref. studysmarter.co.uk.
form the third conditional, use "if" + past perfect in the if-clause and "would/could/might have" + past participle in the main clause.
This structure describes a hypothetical situation in the past, expressing a sense of regret. For example:
"If she had studied, she would have passed the exam."
Using could have + past participle in the main clause
If he had seen the invitation, he could have attended the party.

OP's sentence

: "If it had, I'd call Peter, and we could all go hiking in the forest

If it had stopped raining, I would have called Peter and we could all go hiking in the forest.
This sentence in the First conditional will be -
If it stops raining, I will call Peter and we will all go hiking in the forest.
Mixed conditional.
In OP's sentence, the if clause is in the past perfect and main clause has only "would". (Third conditional+ Second Conditional). So it's a mixed conditional.
We can use mixed conditionals when we imagine a past change with a result in the present or a present change with a result in the past.

Past/Present
Here's a sentence imagining how a change in a past situation would have a result in the present.
If I hadn't got the job in Tokyo, I wouldn't be with my current partner.

So the structure is: If + past perfect >> would + infinitive.

Thanks for the explanation, James. If the rain had stopped, I would call Peter. - I would call him now or in the future. If the rain had stopped, I would have called Peter. - I would have called him by now. The version with "would call" is called a mixed 3rd and 2nd conditional, in which the hypothetical consequence is in the future relative to now. Is this incorrect? Thank you.

@prof1589 You are right. I edited to include the mixed conditional.
It means - John still has time to go hiking with Peter.
